# Simple automorphism proof with lattice elliptic curves?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves

> For a lattice $\Lambda_1=\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}i$, find Aut($E_1$)
>   where $E_1(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1$.

So I know that End($E$) $ =\{\beta \in \mathbb{C} $| $\beta\Lambda \subseteq \Lambda\}$ and Aut($E$) $=\{\beta \in \mathbb{C} $| $\beta\Lambda =\Lambda\}$ but I'm really not sure how to use this information to find the correct automorphisms.

What's a good way to find the   Aut($E_1$)?

Comment: As you point out, you will have $Aut(E_1) = \{\beta\in\mathbb{C}\mid \beta\Lambda_1 = \Lambda_1\}$. Let $\beta = x + iy \in\mathbb{C}$ and consider $\beta\Lambda_1$. You might notice a couple of things: if $\beta=x\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $\beta\in End(E_1) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\subset End(E)$; is there anything else in $End(E_1)$? Then, what does the norm of an element in $End(E_1)$ have to be in order to actually be in $Aut(E_1)$?

Comment: @JohnMartin you mean what would map an element in $End(E_1)$ to $Aut(E_1)$? Could it be the complex conjugate? I'm really not sure.

Comment: No, what I mean is that every automorphism of the curve is already an endomorphism, i.e. $Aut(E_1)\subset End(E_1)$. So determining $End(E_1)$ might help you determine $Aut(E_1)$. 

Hint: There is more in $End(E_1)$ in this case than just $\mathbb{Z}$. What happens if you multiply $\Lambda_1$ by $i$?

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that ${\rm End}(\Bbb C/\Lambda)=\{\lambda\in\Bbb C\mid\lambda\Lambda\subseteq\Lambda\}$ it should be clear that
$$
{\rm Aut}(\Bbb C/\Lambda)=\{\lambda\in\Bbb C\mid\lambda\Lambda=\Lambda\}.
$$
When $\Lambda=\Bbb Z\otimes\Bbb Zi=\Bbb Z[i]$ the latter set is identified with the set of invertible elements in the *ring* $\Bbb Z[i]$ i.e.
$$
\{1,-1,i,-i\}.
$$

---

A variant is to observe that for any $\lambda\in\Bbb Z[i]$ the set $\lambda\Lambda=\lambda\Bbb Z[i]$ is an ideal with
$$
\left|\frac\Lambda{\lambda\Lambda}\right|=|\lambda|
\qquad\text{(complex norm)}
$$
(this can be understood observing that multiplying by $z\in\Bbb C$ an area of a region $A\subset\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$ gets multiplied by a factor $|z|$).
Thus $\lambda\in{\rm Aut}(\Bbb C/\Lambda)$ when $|\lambda|=1$, leading to the same result.

Comment: <1 minute between cross posts. Nice :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest determining $End(E_1)$. To do this, you might note that if $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha(\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z})\subset\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$ and hence $End(E_1) = \mathbb{Z}+i\mathbb{Z}$. Then, the automorphisms will be the endomorphisms of norm 1, that is the units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the cyclic group generated by $i$, which as a set consists of the elements $\{1,-1,i,-i\}$.